# 'MaxScaleDenominator' and 'BBOX' are not working at the same time

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms

Geoserver layer styling part and 'bbox' don't work at the same time.

It is exactly `MaxScaleDenominator` and `wms bbox`.

```xml
<sld:MaxScaleDenominator>30000.0</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
```

```js
var bboxControl = 0.1;

var bbox = (coordinate[0]-bboxControl) + ',' +  
(coordinate[1]-bboxControl) + ',' +  
(coordinate[0]+bboxControl) + ',' +
(coordinate[1]+bboxControl);

var projection = map.getView().getProjection().getCode();

const parameter = "?SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.1.1
&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo
&FORMAT=image/png
&TRANSPARENT=true" 
+ "&QUERY_LAYERS=" + layers
+ "&LAYERS=" + layers
+ "&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage
&INFO_FORMAT=application/json
&FEATURE_COUNT=50
&X=50&Y=50"
+ "&SRS=" + projection
+ "&STYLE=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101"
+ "&BBOX=" + bbox;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: getFeatureInfoUrl + parameter,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(result){
            success(result);
        }           
    });
});
```

If I delete one, the other works.
I don't know how the two relate to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bounding box and image size combination is such that the scale of the (GetMap) image is above 30000.0 then you won't get a GetFeatureInfo response, because there is no feature to query.

You can use the actual GetFeatureInfo request to generate the associated WMS GetMap request and try it in a browser, do you get a non-blank image?

Comment: thanks, If I use 'getMap' it is work.  I can see a map of that area. but getFeatureInfo is not work(application/json). {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":0,"timeStamp":"2019-10-23T00:04:40.968Z","crs":null}. 
I got these results and I don't know why.

Comment: Is there a feature in the map at the query location?